# 301 Redirect for Podcast Feed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, rss

We recently moved from a Clover site to a Wordpress site so the structure on our podcasts has changed. We have two podcast feeds, one for audio, and one for video.

The old podcast feeds were pulling in from these urls...

http://nmconline.net/podcast.php?pageID=27

http://nmconline.net/podcast.php?pageID=28

Our new feeds are sitting at...

http://nmc.church/feed/videopodcast

http://nmc.church/feed/audiopodcast

I've tried the redirect a few different ways but still no luck. I've tried using a straight 301 redirect and just recently move to a RewriteRule, but still won't work. Not sure if its important or not, but I am forwarding the old nmconline.net domain to our new nmc.church domain.

Here is my current .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^podcast\.php?pageID=27 http://nmc.church/feed/videopodcast [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^podcast\.php?pageID=28 http://nmc.church/feed/audiopodcast [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in a `RewriteRule`. Here is how you can do:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageID=27$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^podcast\.php$ http://nmc.church/feed/videopodcast? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageID=28$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^podcast\.php$ http://nmc.church/feed/audiopodcast? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`?` at the end of URL will remove previous query string.

Comment: Actually anubhava, I did a little bit more testing today on this topic and it seems that the first rewrite is successfully redirecting, but the second one is not? The audiopodcast for whatever reason is redirecting to the new one? Thoughts?

Comment: 2nd rule is pretty much same as 1st rule. What happens when you enter `http://nmconline.net/podcast.php?pageID=28` in browser? Did you try clearing browser cache?

Comment: Right! That's why I was confused, but if you navigate to http://nmconline.net/podcast.php?pageID=28 you'll see a 404 error? So it seems the second RewriteRule isn't executing.

Comment: Ah it is fixed now. It lad leftover of `?page` in pattern, try now

Comment: There we go! Thanks again for your help!